# How to solve Calling [toString] on an [Output<T>] is not supported this error from pulumi typescript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pulumi

I am creating a s3 bucket by pulumi typescript and want to use this bucket in EC2 User data for copying an object. Following is my Code for both.

```
const bucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("bucket-name", {
    acl: "private",
});
```

I uploaded a index.html file And here is the user data of EC2:-

```
const userData = 
`#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y apache2 && sudo apt install -y awscli 
aws s3 cp s3://`+pulumi.interpolate`${bucket.id}`+`/index.html /var/www/html/index.html
sudo systemctl start apache2`;
```

I used `pulumi.interpolate`${bucket.id}` for calling bucket Id, but when I checked on EC2 for user data then I get following error.

```
aws s3 cp s3://Calling [toString] on an [Output<T>] is not supported.

To get the value of an Output<T> as an Output<string> consider either:
1: o.apply(v => `prefix${v}suffix`)
2: pulumi.interpolate `prefix${v}suffix`
```

can anyone help how can I call bucket name in script?

Comment: I believe [bucket.s3UrlForObject()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-s3/ibucket.html#aws_s3_IBucket_s3UrlForObject) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You should put `interpolate` outside all the string operations

```
const userData = pulumi.interpolate`#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y apache2 && sudo apt install -y awscli 
aws s3 cp s3://${bucket.id}/index.html /var/www/html/index.html
sudo systemctl start apache2`;
```

If your code, the `+` operation invokes `toString` on the output and leads to the error.

Comment: Hey Thanks, it works for me, One more thing is that, I just remove the brackets.